# Maximization of a complex function with real outputs

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, calculus-of-variations

Let $a$ and $b$ be functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for some real $\alpha$ and $\beta$, there exist complex $z$ and $w$ such that $a(z) = \alpha$ and $b(w) = \beta$.  Given that $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers such that $x + y = z + w$, what is the maximum possible value of $a(x) + b(y)$ in terms of $a,b,\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: There's no upper bound on the value.

Comment: what are $a$ and $b$? do you know these functions' explicit form?

Comment: No I do not know the explicit forms.

Comment: Then @Raskolnikov is correct. There isn't enough information about $a$ and $b$ to place any upper bound whatsoever on $a(x)+b(y)$. There's some important information here you just haven't communicated.